autofac container resolve getting "Dynamic code generation is not supported on this platform" error
I wanna get my dependencies dynamically on asp.net minimal api with this code
_userService = container.Resolve<IUserService>();

but i getting this error
Dynamic code generation is not supported on this platform
I tried change some configs of *.csproj

I found solution
Delete this line in *.csproj
<PublishAot>true</PublishAot>

